# Force delete the data app folder when I install the app

Tags: android

I did an app that copy a file in the app data folder, but I need that when I overwrite my app with a new version the data folder must be deleted.

How can I do it?

Comment: Store the app version in `SharedPreferences` and whenever the MAIN/LAUNCHER `Activity` is started check to see if the current version is newer than the version in `SharedPreferences`. If it is newer then delete the data folder.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Edit:  I misunderstood.  So the question is, you want *your app* to detect that it's installed a new version, and delete the file?

There's no way to have the action performed on install, but you can have it performed on the first run of the new version of your application.  When it runs, do the following.

3 steps:
-When your app is installed, store a SharedPreference with the current version of your app.  You can either hardcode this or pull it from PackageManager using:

```
PackageInfo pInfo = getPackageManager().getPackageInfo(getPackageName(), 0);
version = pInfo.versionName;
```

-Every time your app starts, check that SharedPreference against the current version of the application.  If they match, do nothing.

-If they **don't** match, there's a new version of your app on the device! Delete the file you want to delete, and update the SharedPreference to contain the new version number of your app.

Comment: That's not going to work if the app is installed from the Play Store (obviously).

Comment: Sorry, didn't realize you wanted the app to do the file deletion.  Edited the answer accordingly :)